# c++: stringstream to vector

Tags: c++, vector, stringstream

I'm trying to store the data that is in a stringstream into a vector. I can succesfully do so but it ignores the spaces in the string. How do I make it so the spaces are also pushed into the vector?

Thanks!

Code stub:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream s;
    string line  = "HELLO HELLO\0";

    stringstream stream(line);

    unsigned char temp;
    vector<unsigned char> vec;
    while(stream >> temp) 
        vec.push_back(temp);


    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
         cout << vec[i];
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you treat spaces as part of the items you want to put in your vector, then what is going to separate one item from another?

Comment: Please clarify whether you want your vector to contain (1) one entry per character, (2) one entry per space-separated "word", or (3) a single entry containing everything; and, if (2), where you want any whitespace to go? [EDITED to add: oh, wait, this is a vector of _unsigned char_? Oops, sorry.]

Comment: @Gareth or (4) a word per line

Comment: One entry per character.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why are you using a `stringstream` to copy from a `string` into a `vector<unsigned char>`?  You can just do:

```
vector<unsigned char> vec(line.begin(), line.end());
```

and that will do the copy directly.  If you need to use a `stringstream`, you need to use `stream >> noskipws` first.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the standard streams all skip whitespace. If you wish to disable the skipping of white space you can explicitly do so on the next stream extraction (`>>`) operation by using the noskipws manipulator like so:

```
stream >> std::noskipws >> var;
```

Comment: Note that noskipws is persistent; it applies not only to "the next stream extraction" but to all subsequent operations on that stream until you do something to cancel it. To make the intent clear to readers of the code, it's probably best to do "stream >> std::noskipws;" as a separate statement rather than including it with one particular extraction. (Unless you're turning it on and off in the course of a single chain of >>s. Which I would recommend you not do, for clarity's sake.)

Comment: ahhh, thanks, forgot about that part. I have trouble keeping straight which ones only affect the next operation and which ones don't, as I don't use the stream i/o much... mostly due to lack of low level error checking and reporting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to suggest just using the container that you actually want but you could also use the manipulator `noskipws`

See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) for more info on stringstream and other methods you could use besides the extraction operator

Edit:

Also consider `std::copy` or `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `noskipws` manipulator. Say `stream >> std::noskipws;` before pulling stuff out of it.

<sup>[EDITED to add the `std::` prefix, which I stupidly omitted. Your code doesn't need it because it has `using namespace std;` at the top, but others may choose not to do that.]</sup>